# Play HTML5 Canvas animation onClick or onTouchEnd on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, html, animation, canvas

I have a test site that uses HTML5 Canvas to load an array of stills from a video, then draws them to the Canvas at 24 frames per second. It works great and is currently set up to autoplay once the array has been pre-loaded.The reason for this was to autoplay on iOS.

What I'm trying to do now is instead of autoplaying the image sequence, I want to trigger the `animate()` function by use of `document.getElementById('anim').onclick=animate;` The element ID is a CSS3 ID that has two background elements: the background image (which is the first frame of the image sequence, and a play button). This is shown to the user until all the images have preloaded.

I want the user to simply press the Anim element (anywhere, but there is a play button for the user) and then play the image sequence. After the sequence, hide the canvas element so the background image and play button shows again that way it can be triggered again.

This needs to work on iPhone.

You can view the full source  [here](http://html5canvas.prismstudios.net) to see it in action.

CSS:

```
 #anim { 
        background-image:url('images/play_button.png'),url('images/t5.png');
        background-position: center, left top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height:500px; 
        width:660px;
      }
```

JS:

```
function draw() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('anim').getContext("2d");
            var start = 1, stop = 121,cur=start,imgArr=[];

            var loadLoop = function() {
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.onload = function() {
                    imgArr.push(this);
                    cur++;

                    if(cur > stop) {
                      // all images preloaded
                      // This is where the animate function is called for auto-play
                       animate();
                    }
                    else {
                       loadLoop();
                    }
                }

                img.src = "jpg_80/t5_"+(cur)+".jpg";
            }

            loadLoop();

            function animate() {
                var timer = setInterval(function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(imgArr.shift(), 0, 0 );
                    if(imgArr.length == 0) {
                        // no more frames
                        clearInterval(timer);
                    }
                },1000/24);
            }
        }
```

HTML:

```
 <body>
 <!-- HTML5 Canvas Animation-->
<div>
    <canvas id="anim" width="660" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
    <script>
    //call after page loaded
    window.onload = function() {
         draw();
        // This is where I want the animate function called for manual play
         //document.getElementById('anim').onclick=animate;
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animate is limited to within the scope of the draw function. You can only call the animate function within draw function the way it's currently defined. You probably want Option 2.

Option 1)
If you do the following you'll be able to get the animation to fire on the click.

```
document.getElementById('anim').onclick = draw;
```

Option 2)
If you want to call just the animate function you'll need to declare the animate variable outside of the draw function.

```
var animate;
function draw(){
//...other draw stuff here
    animate = function(){
       //animate stuff here
    }
}
```

You'll then have access to the animate function on global scope.

Comment: First option works! I will try the second option. It's been a while since I used Javascript and I didn't even notice that the `animate()` was wrapped in the `draw()`. I will select your answer then.

Comment: Glad that I could help. Neat animation btw.